# When Hashem spoke to Moshe and it doesn't say leemor it always means that the general public only found this out after it was written in the Torah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

Is it correct to say that when Hashem spoke to Moshe and It doesn't say leemor it means that Klal Yisroel only found this out after the Torah was given?

Comment: Welcome to MY and thanks for this great first question!

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/5245864/jewish/Yisro-What-Happened-at-Sinai.htm

Comment: By the ketores it doesn’t say leemor, and yet they knew about it as soon as the mishkan was built